# SQL Update a column in a table using Trigger to a Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to auto generate a document reference number when a new document is added to an sql table - the reference number is a concatonation of some of the other fields in that table.

Looking online i can see one method is to use the dbid function to generate a uid and then create a function to concatonate and then a trigger on the table on insert to populate the column, but ive spent numerous hours and i cant get it to work.

The table has the following columns:-

```
Table:-     dbo.codeallocations21322        

Columns :-
Dbid        
Projectcode 
Type        
Discipline]     
Hdlreference
```

So the hdlreference column would be populated with :-

```
[projectcode]-[type]-[discipline]-[bdid]
```

With the [bdid] set to 6 characters'.

Eg `21322-rfq-mech-000001` 
Any help would be much appreciated / advise a better way ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is The Terrible Grammar A Scouse Thing?

Comment: I assume SQL-Server because `dbo.`. Please tag your DBMS in future

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JohnHC - will heed your advice, first post. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
alter table codeallocations21322
  add hdlreference 
      as ( projectcode  + '-' + type + '-' + discipline + '-' + dbid);
```

Comment: Many thanks for that answer @JohnHC - altered it slightly to convert the dbID to a Varchar :-

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks John - altered slightly to convert the Int dbID to a varchar and works great :-

```
alter table CodeAllocations21322

  add hdlreference2

    as (ProjectCode  + '-' + Type + '-' + Discipline + '-' + right('00000' + Cast (dbID AS varchar(5)), 5));
```

Thanks again, look forward to talking to you in the future.